# Set new document in Firestore using variable as ID

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to create a new document in Firestore and name it after a variable?

I tried modifying the example provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) but to no avail.

This is what I attempted:

```
import time

#declare unix variable
unix = int(time.time())

#gcp boilerplate dictionary
data = {
'name': 'Los Angeles',
'state': 'CA',
'country': 'USA'
}

#create new doc under collection with fields form dictionary
db.collection('cities').document(unix).set(data)
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: No new document is created when I try to name it after my 'unix' variable. It seems like document names can only be hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a document ID to [`CollectionReference.document()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_collection.BaseCollectionReference.document), it has to be a string argument. It can be a hard-coded string, but it can also be a variable: as long as that variable is a string.

```
db.collection('cities').document(str(unix)).set(data)
```

Comment: I completely overlooked that aspect, thank you for pointing that out, much appreciated.